# Check if linq object is referenced

Tags: linq, object-reference

What is the best (fastest) way to check if a linq object is referenced from another table. Normaly i do this way but i guess this might be slow on bigger tables.

```
CurrentObject.ReferencingObjects.Count != 0
```

This might be faster.

```
CurrentObject.ReferencingObjects.FirstOrDefault() != null
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ReferencingObjects` implements `ICollection<T>` (which it appears to, given that it has a `Count` *property*), the first option is likely actually faster, as `Count` (for most implementations) is often stored directly, so this effectively is just a property looking up a field directly.

If, however, you were using `Enumerable.Count()` (the method, not a property), then my preferred method would instead be to use:

```
CurrentObject.ReferencingObjects.Any();
```

As the `Any()` method is very clearly showing your intent, and also very quick in general.